# Emulator preview is not same to actual device

Tags: android, layout, android-emulator, android-relativelayout

I have made a simple layout that has an `ImageView` and two `Buttons`.

The layout as it shows on the preview is as follows:

[Layout as shown in android studio preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9lJj.png)

Where I run the emulator that I created for Lg3 (5.5" with 1440x2560), I get the following result (good result just like I designed)

[Emulator result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQW9s.png)

However, when I actually download the apk to the real Lg3 device, the result is as follows:

[Actual result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0KFB.jpg)

I tried using layout-normal, layout-small, layout-large however none worked.

The `.xml` looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/White"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/main_background"
    android:layout_width="230dp"
    android:layout_height="230dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="115dp"
    android:src="@drawable/main_background" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Sign_In"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/main_background"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@drawable/white_buttons"
    android:fontFamily="@font/assistant"
    android:text="Sign In"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="@color/Fonts"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Sign_Up"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Sign_In"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/colored_buttons"
    android:fontFamily="@font/assistant"
    android:text="Sign Up"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="@color/White"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I was wondering if there is something im doing wrong that creates unequal result between the emulator and the real device.

Thank you very much

Comment: My guess is that the screen density of the actual device is different than the screen density configured in the AVD. In terms of your layout, your design assumes a minimum screen height of `645dp` (`115dp` top margin and `230dp` height for the image, `160dp` top margin and `60dp` height for `Sign_In`, and `20dp` top margin and `60dp` height for `Sign_Up`). That is about 4", and there will be a lot of devices will smaller screens than that.

Comment: checkout my addition to the answer as well, hopefully it teaches you something :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As *CommonsWare* mentioned - it may be because of different screen density.

My recommendation to you is to use [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout) to develop one layout for all screen sizes.

From the documentation:

> ConstraintLayout allows you to create large and complex layouts with a flat view hierarchy (no nested view groups). It's similar to RelativeLayout in that all views are laid out according to relationships between sibling views and the parent layout, but it's more flexible than RelativeLayout and easier to use with Android Studio's Layout Editor.

**Here is an example using `ConstraintLayout` without using fixed-sized values on your views:**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@null"
  tools:context=".MainActivity">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars[14]" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**It will look like this:**

[image]

For more information about `ConstraintLayout` you can also  [guidelines](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/guidelines.html) and [Chains](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/create_chains.html) to support different screen sizes.

Comment: But when you say different screen density, I designed it in android studio for the exact density as the real device. Shouldnt it be equal then?

Comment: As *CommonsWare* mentioned - you should check the screen density configured in the AVD. General, instead of using a single layout for every screen size you can use *ConstraintLayout* to make one flexible layout for all screen sizes.

Comment: However, if doing this by using constraint layer, and then in order to keep the image above the button I still use specific distance as 100dp, how do I make sure it wont create too big distance in some screens?

Comment: For that you can say to your views - you will be as 50% width as your screen using  `app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5"` and 
    `app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.5"` for height

Comment: The best way to learn how to use this type of layout if to read the documentation and practice making layouts. You will see that as time goes by you will manage to build complicated UI with a matter of a few minutes.

Comment: just wanted to add something in as well, I agree with the current answer though :)